# How to replace NA with cero in a columns, if the columns beside have a values? using R

Tags: r, if-statement, replace, na, missing-data

I want to know a way to replace the NA of a column if the columns beside have a value, this because, using a  example if the worker have values in the other columns mean he went to work that day so if he have an NA  it means that should be replaced with cero, and if there are no values in the columns surrounding means he didnt go to work that day and the NA is correct

I have been doing this by sorting the other columns but its so time consuming

A sample of my data called df, the real one have 30 columns and like 30,000 rows

```
  df <- data.frame(
  hours = c(NA, 3, NA, 8), 
  interactions = c(NA, 3, 9, 9),
  sales = c(1, 1, 1, NA)
)
```

Comment: You mention *"went to work that day"* but there's no indication of "day" in your data. While it's not hard to look at previous/next values to replace `NA` values, the logic needs to know if the next or previous value is the same day. Further, there is no concept of "worker id" or similar here to uniquely identify people in the data. Are there more columns in your data that would better track and inform that discussion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also do as follows:

```
library(dplyr)

mutate(df, X = if_else(is.na(hours) | is.na(interactions), 0, hours))

#   hours interactions sales X
# 1    NA           NA     1 0
# 2     3            3     1 3
# 3    NA            9     1 0
# 4     8            9    NA 8
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df$hours2 <- ifelse(
  test = is.na(df$hours) & any(!is.na(df[,c("interactions", "sales")])),
  yes = 0, 
  no = df$hours)

df
  hours interactions sales hours2
1    NA           NA     1      0
2     3            3     1      3
3    NA            9     1      0
4     8            9    NA      8
```

Comment: Looks nice, is there any way to achieve this via `across` and `cur_column()+1` `cur_column()-1` for instance without mentioning the names of the variables explicitly?

Comment: Thanks. I'll leave the dplyr stuff to the dplyr folks. I'm very much of an amateur with that syntax. One option in base would be to define the columns as `setdiff(names(df), "hours")`